# can kinetic work with indigo over a network?

Tags: ros-kinetic, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am building a network that will include a laptop, some Raspberry pi's, Jetson TK1, Odroid C2, etc. The laptop has kinetic installed, but the ARM boards all have indigo as it seems that is the only distro that will work on the ARMs. Will this work? Is there an issue with nodes being on different releases? I imagine it would be simple enough to revert the laptop to indigo, but I'd rather not as I think that would mean reverting my OS as well (currently Ubuntu 16.04).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247045/can-kinetic-work-with-indigo-over-a-network?/) by [richkappler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2694/richkappler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2016-11-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a few relevant Q/As on here already, see for instance [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/37403/ros-backwards-compatibility-in-distributed-system/) or [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/74167/using-fuerte-and-groovy-in-the-same-machine/).

In short: It probably works, if message definitions between both ROS versions did not change. Note that this is a officially non-supported and thus not recommended use case however.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2